# Is there a way to change MySQL root password during re-installation (Windows 10)?

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I have forgotten my password for my MySQL server and it won't let me configure my MySQL server as I don't know the root password. MySQL is not currently installed on my machine ; I am trying to re-install it. Does anyone know how to change the root password during re-installation?

[Where I can not login because I have forgotten my password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rI2L.png)

[The error I get when I try the reset procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOurF.png)

Comment: If MySql is not installed on your computer, surely it has no password either?

Comment: Actually it does have a password as the server was previously set up on my machine.

Comment: MySql *is* the server. I assume now you are talking about reinstalling a client-side tool such as MySql Workbench.

Comment: Yes I've uploaded a picture of where I cannot enter my password.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html?

Comment: @GSerg I have edited in a picture of the errors that I get when I try to reset using the method.